# laravel 4 - empty routes via Artisan::call()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

If I use the following:

```
Artisan::call('routes')
```

It returns 0.

I was hoping to parse the same routes that appears when I run `php artisan routes` from CLI.

Has anyone tried this with success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need artisan - just use the routes class itself:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Routes</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(Route::getRoutes() as $name => $route)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```